# javascript regex to check for certain special characters in a url

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a javascript regex to validate an streaming video url which starts with http or rtmp and whose length is <= 100 and which does not contain `# % +` , characters. I have come up with `(http|rtmp)://.{10,93}` for the first part and `/^[^#%+,]+$/g` for the second requirement.

I'm confused about combining these into a single regex. I'd appreciate any help in this direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you not simply combine them like this?

`^(http|rtmp)://[^#%+,]{10,93}$`

Then you'd have `http` or `rtmp` followed by `://` and between 10 and 93 characters which are outside of the ones you wish to exclude.

Comment: thanks for the expression. Regex has always foxed me and I intend to spend some time practising it.